# how to set secure flag for cookies inplay 2.1.0

Tags: security, playframework, http-headers

I am using play 2.1.0. I want to set a secure flag for request headers. I tried using application.session.cookie.secure=true  in application.conf with https host. But still the security flag is not set in header.

Did not find much on internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a link to accompanying Play documentation to hand, but the configuration property you're looking for is:

```
session.secure=true
```

You can take a look in the [source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala) on the 2.1.x branch to see how Play uses this property.

Comment: Thanks avik. Documentation available at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Session$